# Find cofactors for polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given $f(t) = t^3-6t^2+t+4$ and $g(t) = t^5-6t+1$. I have to find the gcd (which I have already done) and then find cofactors $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ such that $gcd(f,g) = 1 = pf + qg$. I have no idea how to do this other than try around (which could take quite a while). What am I missing here?

Comment: The standard method is to reconstruct then from the quotients produced when carrying out the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get $1$ without allowing fractions.

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  +  x  + 4 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  +  x  + 4 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 6 x  + 35 \right) } +  \left(  200 x^{2}  - 65 x  - 139 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  +  x  + 4 \right)  =  \left(  200 x^{2}  - 65 x  - 139 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 40 x  - 227 }{ 8000 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 1195 x  + 447 }{ 8000 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  200 x^{2}  - 65 x  - 139 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 1195 x  + 447 }{ 8000 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 76480000 x  - 3752000 }{ 57121 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ -7730176}{57121 } \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{  - 1195 x  + 447 }{ 8000 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ -7730176}{57121 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 68259595 x  - 25533087 }{ 61841408000 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 6 x  + 35 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  + 6 x  + 35 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 40 x  - 227 }{ 8000 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 40 x^{3}  + 13 x^{2}  + 38 x  + 55 }{ 8000 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 40 x  - 227 }{ 8000 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 76480000 x  - 3752000 }{ 57121 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 382400 x^{4}  - 143040 x^{3}  - 312256 x^{2}  - 200896 x  + 1973440 }{ 57121 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 382400 x^{2}  + 2151360 x  + 163584 }{ 57121 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 68259595 x  - 25533087 }{ 61841408000 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 57121 x^{5}  + 342726 x  - 57121 }{ 7730176 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 57121 x^{3}  + 342726 x^{2}  - 57121 x  - 228484 }{ 7730176 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 6 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 5975 x^{2}  + 33615 x  + 2556 }{ 120784 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  +  x  + 4 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 5975 x^{4}  - 2235 x^{3}  - 4879 x^{2}  - 3139 x  + 30835 }{ 120784 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$